# Can Deferred.callback() or Deferred.errback() raise an exception to the caller?

Tags: python, twisted, twisted.internet

Can there be a condition where calling `.callback()` or `.errback()` will raise an exception to the caller where it won't be captured by the deferred?

Say I have the the following deferred and callbacks:

```
from twisted.internet import defer

def bad_callback(result):
    raise Exception()

def bad_errback(result):
    raise Exception()

d = defer.Deferred()
d.addCallbacks(bad_callback, bad_errback)
```

If I call `d.callback(None)`, the result in `d` will be the `Exception` from `bad_callback()`. If I call `d.errback(Exception())`, the result in `d` will be the `Exception` raised from `bad_errback()`. But, in either of those cases the exceptions will not be raised to the caller.

Now, I do know of a couple conditions where calling `.callback()` or `.errback()` will raise an exception to the caller, but those are conditions where you violate the proper use of deferreds.

- Obviously, if you call `.callback()` or `.errback()` with an improper number of arguments, it will raise a `TypeError`.
- Calling an already called deferred will raise `AlreadyCalledError`.
- Calling `.callback(defer.Deferred())` will raise an `AssertionError`.
- Calling `.errback()` is equivalent to calling `.errback(failure.Failure())` which will raise `NoCurrentExceptionError` if there is no active exception.

Really my question comes down to: can I safely rely on the behavior that calling `.callback(result)` or `.errback(exception_or_failure)` with a result will never raise an exception so long as the deferred has not already been called and the result is proper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran your example, adding two lines to the bottom:

```
d.callback(None)
print("OK!")
```

and got this output:

```
Unhandled error in Deferred:
Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "callbacks.py", line 11, in <module>
    d.callback(None)
  File ".../twisted/internet/defer.py", line 368, in callback
    self._startRunCallbacks(result)
  File ".../twisted/internet/defer.py", line 464, in _startRunCallbacks
    self._runCallbacks()
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File ".../twisted/internet/defer.py", line 551, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "callbacks.py", line 4, in bad_callback
    raise Exception()
exceptions.Exception: 
OK!
```

So in this specific case (as you have determined yourself), no, the exception won't be re-raised.

In the general case, there are a few places where exceptions will *effectively* propagate out; if you have a `MemoryError` because you are totally out of memory, it's likely that the `Deferred` implementation itself will allocate a little memory somewhere by attempting to call a function or something and that exception will come back to you.

But this is just a risk of programming in Python in general; there are several exceptions (`MemoryError`, `KeyboardInterrupt`) which may arise with no warning.  If your whole process isn't burning down, then no, `callback` and `errback` won't raise exceptions except in the cases you've outlined.